# Format dates output from excel using panda

Tags: python, pandas, date

I'm trying to print out data values extracted from excel file using pandas but the dates are coming with hours values as well

the code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\gits\PCIv1.xlsm',sheet_name=9,names=None)

df = df.dropna()
print(df)
```

the output

```
  Unnamed: 0             Unnamed: 1           Unnamed: 2
0         ID                   Loja                 Data
6         19  B019 BOMPREÇO PIEDADE  2020-05-17 00:00:00
```

I want to eliminate the '00:00:00' and keep only the day/month in format DD/MM

Any help?

Tks

Comment: On the column with the date make sure the datatype is datetime and use something like df[“date”].str.apply(lambda x: x.strftime(“%d/%m”)

Comment: @JQadrad, this will cause value error since value in 0th index is not a valid date pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use converters while reading the excel which will make your life easier, then you have to apply `dt.strftime`

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx', converters = {'Date' : pd.to_datetime})
df2['Date'] = df2['Date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m')
df2
```

Try the below code (Format the field after reading the excel)

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['A','B','A','B','C']
                    , 'ID':[3,4,3,5,6]
                    , 'Date':['2019-12-10 00:00:00','2019-12-10 00:00:00','2019-12-10 00:00:00'
                              ,'2019-12-10 00:00:00','2019-12-10 00:00:00']})
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", errors="coerce").dt.strftime('%d/%m')
df1
```

Then write your DataFrame into the Excel

Comment: great! df['Data'] = df['Data'].dt.strftime('%d/%m') gave me a perfect solution! Tks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\gits\PCIv1.xlsm',sheet_name=9)
pd.to_datetime(df['Data'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", errors="coerce").dt.strftime("%d-%m")
```

[to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)